# When I try to get an Item from a data set I get "0" for every row

Tags: sql, .net, dataset

I'm running the following SQL through Visual Basic

```
SELECT distinct(schemecode) from CondatControl.dbo.xtblSchemeNotes order by SchemeCode"
schemes = RunSql(strSQL)
```

(The RunSql function is the same function that all other connection and data sets for this program are run and so I can safely say that the error is not there)

When I run the query through our database it comes back with 84 rows with just the scheme code and the code running the connection and query don't through up any errors.

Unfortunately when I go to use the schemecode data for the process that I am coding:

```
For Each row as DataRow In schemes.Tables(o).Rows
currentscheme = row.Item("schemecode")
msgbox currentscheme 'this is for testing purposes.
Next
```

All I get is 0 returned for every row and I have no idea why.
In the data the scheme code has a datatype char(3) and is populated with 84 rows of three letter codes.

Any help here guys? I hope that I not just going code blind late on a Friday night and its something simple.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: Does your DataTable contain the expected number of rows?  What do you see in the debugger when you peek inside the `schemes` object after loading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is the exact code text or there aren't any variable names that are global? Ex: lower case "o" that is used for Tables collection index would be invalid if not defined. And is the "row" variable defined anywhere else? It is suspicious that it is defined in upper case, but in your loop it is lower-case.

This following code returns distinct 3 char values from a table:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim connectionString As String = "[Enter Connection String]"
Dim queryString As String = "select distinct(schemecode) from dbo.xtblSchemeNotes order by SchemeCode"
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

Try
    connection.Open()

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection)

    da.Fill(ds)
    connection.Close()
    connection = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    connection.Close()
    connection = Nothing
End Try

Dim currentscheme As String
For Each schemaRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

    currentscheme = schemaRow.Item("schemecode")
    MsgBox(currentscheme) 'this is for testing purposes.
Next
```

Comment: Hi EhzI, the mistake difference in the capitalisation of Row was just an error by me when typing it in to the forum. I renamed the variable rows to schemeRow as suggested by you and it now works. I'm not sure if it has something to do with row being a reserved word or something but it now works correctly. Thanks!